# How to customize show time of NSUserNotification when using banner type

Tags: nsusernotificationcenter

On Mac OS 10.8, the banner is shown a few seconds and disappeared automatically,
so how to set the duration to show the banner with code.

I also read NSUserNotification API document, it seems only has API to schedule and repeat the notification.